# Как сделать в input number для webkit, чтобы стрелочки были видны не только при наведении?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, webkit

В интернете полно ответов, как полностью скрыть их. Но мне нужно, чтобы они показывались всегда, как в firefox. 
Можно ли вообще так сделать? Или эта штука не кроссбраузерна?

Answer (score 1):

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="input"/>
```